# Error trying to Access BigQuery using API key(Simple API Access)

Tags: google-app-engine, google-api, google-bigquery

```
    401 Unauthorized

- Show headers -

{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Login Required",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Login Required"
 }
}
```

I'm getting the above error while trying to Access BigQuery using API key(Simple API Access)
Any knows y it is so??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What type of application are you trying to build?

BigQuery doesn't support access by API key, but it does support a variety of authorization flows, including using service account authorization. Read more about which [BigQuery API authorization flow to choose](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/authorization).

Comment: well i'm building a simple Web application which accesses data from bigquery sample dataset and visualize that data using some graphs.So u mean anyone who views my web application needs to login using a valid google account with BigQuery api enabled.Will dat be always required.Isn't there any way i can avoid the user from doing dat.

Comment: Ok, then you should build your application using App Engine Service Account flow (meaning that Application itself is authorized to access the BigQuery API). The manner and code to accomplish this is described here: https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/authorization#service-accounts-appengine. Read the documentation on that page for "server to server" authorization, it describes exactly what you need. (https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/authorization#service-accounts)